# Erro ao Cadastrar no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou recebndo o seguinte erro ao tentar inserir alguns dados no banco de dados:

> Unknown column 'F' in 'field list'

No caso a coluna e do tipo enum e pode receber 'M', ou 'F', testando diretamente no banco de dados vi que esse erro ocorre quando passamos o valor sem aspas, acredito que estou passando o valor de forma errada no script.

PHP

```
$cpf    = $_POST['cpf'];
$idade  = $_POST['idade'];
$sexo   = $_POST['sexo'];

$cpf_novo = limpaCPF($cpf);

$sql_cadastrar_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into tb_usuario VALUES ('".$cpf."', ".$idade.", '".$sexo."')");

if($sql_cadastrar_usuario){
    $erro = "Pesquisa enviada com Sucesso!";
}else{
    $erro = "Erro ao cadastrar dados no banco de dados! - Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Tabela

```
create table tb_usuario (
cpf varchar(14) not null primary key,
idade int not null,
sexo enum ('M', 'F') not null
);
```

Comment: Dê um `var_dump` na sua variável `$sexo`, e veja qual o conteúdo.

Comment: Perfeito amigo , com isso solucionei o problema, no meu formulário eu troquei os campos, no sexo eu passei a idade e na idade o sexo , aí na hora de inserir eu tava tentando colocar a idade no campo sexo ...não conhecia esse comando , valeu .

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo uma tentativa:

**o seu:**

```
$sql_cadastrar_usuario = my:sqli_query($conn, "insert into tb_usuario VALUES ('".$cpf."', ".$idade.", '".$sexo."')");
```

**tenta assim:**

```
$sql_cadastrar_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into tb_usuario VALUES ('$cpf', '$idade', '$sexo')");
```

Comment: Tranquilo cara, então ..já testei também dessa forma , e o erro continua ...

Comment: Acabei de mudar, vc já tentou assim?

Comment: @Joab Bispo, se você vai inserir todos os campos da tabela, não é necessário colocar os campos que irá inserir, portanto a primeira sintaxe e a segunda estão corretas, o problema dele é outro.

Comment: Tentei também sem as aspas, da erro também ..